# Image not shown correctly

Tags: tkinter, random

I have created an image viewing app for previewing an image in the folder which contains 4 images such as bicycle, car, plane, and ship. The app has 2 buttons which are added button and the remove button before the image is viewed it is required to resize to a certain size. Following is my code:

```
type here
import random
from tkinter import *
from PIL import ImageTk, Image 

upper = Toplevel()
upper.title('New Session')
upper.geometry('800x720')
upper.config(bg="#d7dae2")
upper.resizable(False, False)

values = ['bicycle', 'car', 'plane', 'ship']
deck = []
player = []

for card in values:
    deck.append(f'{card}')

def resize_cards(card):
    global our_card_image
    our_card_img = Image.open(card)
    our_card_resize_image = our_card_img.resize((130, 130))
    our_card_image = ImageTk.PhotoImage(our_card_resize_image)
    return our_card_image
   
def add():
    global player_image, our_card_image, card
    try:
        card = random.choice(deck)
       
        # Remove the card from deck
        deck.remove(card)
        # Append card to player list
        player.append(card)
        
        # print(player_image)
        print(player)
        
        player_image = resize_cards(f'How Tkinter - Learning App\images\{card}.png')
        player_label.config(image=player_image)
  
        
        hex.config(text=f'{len(player)}/{len(values)}')
    except:
        hex.config(text=0)

def remove():
    global player_label, player_image
    try:
        deck.append(card)
        player.pop()   

        player_image = resize_cards(f'How Tkinter - Learning App\images\{card}.png')
        player_label.config(image=player_image)
        hex.config(text=f'{len(player)}/{len(values)}')
    except:
        hex.config(text=f'{len(player)}/{len(values)}')

session_frame = Frame(upper)
session_frame.place(x=20, y=40)
       
player_label = Label(session_frame, image='', bg='white')
player_label.pack(padx=10, ipady=10, side=RIGHT)

plus = Button(upper, text='   +   ',
                   font=('Helvatica', 12, 'bold'), command=add)
plus.place(x=760, y=0)
    
minus = Button(upper, text='   -   ',
                    font=('Helvatica', 12, 'bold'), command=remove)
minus.place(x=760, y=35)
    
hex = Label(upper, text=' #/# ', height= 2,
                  font=('Helvatica', 12, 'bold'))
hex.place(x=760, y=70)

root.mainloop()
```

The add function is working properly. However, the remove function has a bug, when it removes the previous item, did not display the correct image. For example:

1. When I clicked add button
   terminal: 'bicycle' the image shows a bicycle.
2. When I clicked add button again
   terminal: 'bicycle', 'car' the image shows the car.
3. When I clicked the remove button (to remove the car image)
   terminal: 'bicycle' but the image remains to show the car, instead of the bicycle.

How to fixed it?[[enter image description here]
[[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cztAS.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OUG5n.png)(https://i.stack.imgur.com/jumHB.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/O2ga5.png)

To fix the remove function to show the correct image.

Comment: You should change this `upper = Toplevel()`  to `upper = Tk()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Inside `remove()`, you always append the global `card` to `deck` and always show the image of `card`.

You need to append the *card* removed from `player` to `deck` and then show the image of *the last card* in `player` instead.

Below is the modified `remove()`:

```py
def remove():
    global player_label, player_image
    try:
        card = player.pop() # remove last card from player
        deck.append(card) # append the card to deck

        if len(player) > 0:
            # show last card in player
            player_image = resize_cards(f'images/{player[-1]}.png')
            player_label.config(image=player_image)
        else:
            # show no image
            player_label.config(image="")
        hex.config(text=f'{len(player)}/{len(values)}')
    except:
        hex.config(text=f'{len(player)}/{len(values)}')
```